# Anchor tag not working in hotmail

Tags: html, email, yii2, html-email

I am new to yii. Anchor tag not working in hotmail when i send mail.

```
<p><?= Html::a(Html::encode($link), $link) ?></p>
```

the link is not clickable

the output is

```
[app-dev.test.com?token=sdfsdfsdf]app-dev.test.com?token=sdfsdfsdf
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way to use anchor element in Yii2. You are providing the url in title attribute of the tag. The correct way is:

`<?php echo Html::a('Link Title', Html::encode($link),['data-pjax'=>0,'class'=>'yourCssClass']);?>`

Hope this helps.